# Will the change of mean/variance of data impact the svm classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, python

I have seen in many areas people scale their data before passing to a classifier or learning algorithm . I noticed that by doing that classifier would be really fast. For instance in python `X=preprocessing.scale(X)` is used before doing `svm.SVC().fit(X,y)` . Does this have any effect on classifier?

Edit : `X=preprocessing.scale(X)` is supposed to

> Standardize a dataset along any axis Center to the mean and component
>   wise scale to unit variance.

Does scaling to unit variance have any effect?

Comment: See here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65094/why-scaling-is-important-for-the-linear-svm-classification or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436367/svm-scaling-input-values or here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77876/why-would-scaling-features-decrease-svm-performance/77894#77894  If those don't help then please elaborate on what specifically you don't understand.